# Monitor pixelated at 1920x1080 resolution with Nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

I have a Geforce GTX 1650 Super graphics card installed on a Debian 10 machine with version 460.39 of the Nvidia driver. I used the installer from the Nvidia's website as this driver has CUDA 11, which I need to run the DaVinci Resolve video editing software. The Debian backports don't have this for Debian 10, from what I've seen.

The Geforce card is connected via an HDMI cable to a Samsung T27A550 TV which has 1920x1080 resolution. The card is working fine at 1680x1050 however at 1920x1080 the screen becomes pixelated.

Before I installed the nvidia drivers I was using, if I’m not wrong, the resolution of 1856x1392. Since installing the drivers this resolution no long appears as an option in the monitor control panel or nvidia-settings. I tried adding it with:

```
xrandr --newmode “1856x1392” 218.06 1856 1992 2192 2528 1392 1393 1396 1440 -HSync +Vsync
```

and then:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1856x1392
```

but I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) ....
```

I've read though that the Nvidia driver does not permit the use of xrandr in this way.

Also tried setting the ViewPortIn, ViewPortOut and Panning in the advanced Display config of nvidia-settings with 1856x1392. ViewPortIn and Panning get set however ViewPortOut does not. It accepts  ViewPortOut of 1680x1050+0+0. This fixes the pixelation when applied however the screen is distorted.

I also tried various things with /etc/X11/xorg.conf, although I’m not even sure if the file is being used.

I’ve tried all of the Samsung setting (TV Menu->Screen Adjustment->Picture Size). eg. 16:9, 4:3, fit screen, etc., but it doesn’t help the pixelation at 1920x1080. I also checked with a second TV with HDMI input and the problems are the same. Neither of the TVs has any overscan settings, although the second TV does have a “no scaling” setting.

Ideally I’d like to use a higher resolution than 1680×1050, something up to 1920x1080.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do either of the TVs have a "game" mode?

Comment: There's an "entertain" Picture Mode but selecting that doesn't help. Thanks

Comment: Nvidia Control Panel, on Windows at least, has an overscan adjustment area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4g1m.png don't know about Linux but maybe....

Comment: This is curious, I see that other linux installations have "underscan" setting. On mine it's missing: https://postimg.cc/njT8RKKj

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129139/ubuntu-18-04-overscan-underscan-issues seems to suggest that there is a `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan on` command. Otherwise more possibilities at https://www.google.com/search?&q=linux+enable+underscan

Comment: searching through this and trying some things, so far no luck but thanks. I did find the game mode. Tried it. Just seemed to make the screen go a little darker.

Answer (score 1):

While following the google suggestion of Mokubai, I found an unexpected solution to the problem. It involved discovering a remedy for the “BadMatch” errors given by xrandr, done by overriding EDID. See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#xrandr_BadMatch

With the change made to /etc/X11/xorg.conf (which I had previously created afresh using nvidia-settings) and after a reboot, I tested xrandr with this:

```
xrandr --newmode “1920x1080_new” 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 “1920x1080_new”
```

This use of xrandr may have had nothing to do with the solution but when I opened nvidia-settings again I found that various new resolutions were present. 1920x1080 continues not to work however a new entry for 1920x1200 does. So problem solved. Strangely, 1680x1050, which used to work, no longer does, however 1680x900 (new) does and does not appear to be distorted in any way given the change in aspect ratio.

Also, after doing all this the "underscan" parameter now appears in nvidia-settings although doesn't enable the use of 1920x1080.